# Continuity of Operator Norm

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ be the set of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\phi: L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$A \mapsto \|A\| := \sup\{\|Ax\| : \|x\| = 1\}$.

I'm trying to give a direct proof that $\phi$ is continuous but I'm having quite a bit of difficulty even getting started.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

To add some context to the question, I was trying to construct my own proof of the fact that if $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if $f: K \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ then there exists some $M \geq 0$ such that

$\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq M\|x-y\|$

for all $x,y \in K$.

My initial plan was as follows (although I believe it requires $K$ to be convex): The mean value theorem yields a point $c \in \{ta + (1-t)b : t \in [0,1]\}$ such that

$f(x) - f(y) = Df(c)(x-y)$

from which it follows that

$\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq \|Df(c)\|\|(x-y)\|$

where the operator norm is the one defined in my original question. If I could somehow bound $\|Df\|$ on $K$ then I would be done. Well I know that a continuous function on $K$ is bounded since $K$ is compact and so I wanted to show that the map $x \mapsto \|Df(x)\|$ was continuous. Well the map $x \mapsto Df(x)$ is continuous since $f$ was assumed to be $C^1$ and so all that was required was the result in my original question since then the result would follow from the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous.

For some reason it did not occur to me to consider the fact that all norms are continuous functions, which follows (as was pointed out to me) from the well known $|a| = |a-b+b|$ tricks from basic analysis which transfer over to normed vector spaces.

The requirement that $\{ta + (1-t)b : t \in [0,1]\} \subset K$ is bugging me at the moment since currently this means that I need to strengthen my hypothesis, adopt a different approach, or that the fact I'm trying to prove is, in fact, wrong!

**EDIT 2**

I've just realised that I have used the mean value theorem incorrectly, at this stage I'm going to look up some standard proofs and see if any were similar in approach to mine

Comment: Show that the operator is bounded. Once, you know that use the fact that bounded and linear operators are continuous.

Comment: @Boby The map $A \mapsto \| A \|$ is not linear.

Comment: Strictly speaking, to prove continuity we need to know how you're defining continuity of functions from $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Usually the norm you've written would be part of this definition.

Comment: @Ian I've added some more context to the original question

Answer (score 3):

Continuity of $\phi$ means: if $A_n\to A$ in $L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$, then $\phi(A_n)=\|A_n\|\to \phi(A)=\|A\|$.

So from $\|A_n-A\|\to 0$ we need to conclude $\|A_n\|-\|A\|\to 0$..

Hint: use the triangle inequality!